# Sum a union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I'm using Microsoft SQL Svr Mgmt Studio 2008.  I don't have access to create a temporary table (company restricts ability to create or modify tables) or I would use that to solve this problem.

I have successfully used a union query to combine the results of three select queries.  Now I am trying to sum the results of the union.

When I execute the query below I receive:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'
```

And then when I remove the group by I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

Here's my query so far:

```
Select Period, PCC, SUM(BasicHits), SUM(FareHits), SUM(SearchHits)
From (

SELECT     AAAPeriod AS Period, 
AAAFromPCC AS PCC, 
- SUM(AAABasic) AS BasicHits,
- SUM(AAAFare) AS FareHits,
- SUM(AAASearch) AS SearchHits
FROM        HitsAaa
HAVING     (AAAPeriod = N'2010-10') 

UNION ALL

SELECT     AAAPeriod, 
AAAtoPCC,
SUM(AAABasic),
SUM(AAAFare),
SUM(AAASearch) 
FROM        HitsAaa
HAVING     (AAAPeriod = N'2010-10')

UNION ALL

SELECT      AgtPeriod, 
AgtPcc, 
SUM(AgtBasic),
SUM(AgtFare),
SUM(AgtSearch)
FROM          HitsAgent
HAVING      (AgtPeriod = N'2010-10')

)GROUP BY Period, PCC
```

I haven't been able to find a solution to this on any of the previous questions.

Comment: The first 2 queries are the same? (And all three are missing a `GROUP BY`). And your derived table needs a table alias.

Comment: You were correct I had deleted the group by in error on the sub queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to alias your derived table, you must also use a group by with a having clause.

```
SELECT
  q1.Period, 
  q1.PCC, 
  SUM(q1.BasicHits), 
  SUM(q1.FareHits), 
  SUM(q1.SearchHits)
FROM (SELECT     
        AAAPeriod AS Period, 
        AAAFromPCC AS PCC, 
        - SUM(AAABasic) AS BasicHits,
        - SUM(AAAFare) AS FareHits,
        - SUM(AAASearch) AS SearchHits
      FROM HitsAaa
      GROUP BY 
        AAAPeriod, 
        AAAFromPCC
      HAVING (AAAPeriod = N'2010-10') 

      UNION ALL

      SELECT     
        AAAPeriod AS Period, 
        AAAtoPCC AS PCC,
        SUM(AAABasic) AS BasicHits,
        SUM(AAAFare) AS FareHits,
        SUM(AAASearch) AS SearchHits 
      FROM HitsAaa
      GROUP BY 
        AAAPeriod, 
        AAAtoPCC
      HAVING (AAAPeriod = N'2010-10')

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        AgtPeriod AS Period, 
        AgtPcc AS PCC, 
        SUM(AgtBasic) AS BasicHits,
        SUM(AgtFare) AS FareHits,
        SUM(AgtSearch)  AS SearchHits
      FROM HitsAgent
      GROUP BY 
        AgtPeriod, 
        AgtPCC
      HAVING (AgtPeriod = N'2010-10')) q1 
GROUP BY 
  q1.Period, 
  q1.PCC
```

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server requires that you define a table alias for a derived table/inline view:

```
SELECT x.period, x.pcc, SUM(x.BasicHits), SUM(x.FareHits), SUM(x.SearchHits)
  FROM (SELECT AAAPeriod AS Period, 
               AAAFromPCC AS PCC, 
               - SUM(AAABasic) AS BasicHits,
               - SUM(AAAFare) AS FareHits,
               - SUM(AAASearch) AS SearchHits
          FROM HitsAaa
         WHERE AAAPeriod = N'2010-10'
      GROUP BY aaaperiod, aaafrompcc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AAAPeriod, 
               AAAtoPCC,
               SUM(AAABasic),
               SUM(AAAFare),
               SUM(AAASearch) 
          FROM HitsAaa
         WHERE AAAPeriod = N'2010-10'
      GROUP BY aaaperiod, aaafrompcc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT AgtPeriod, 
               AgtPcc, 
               SUM(AgtBasic),
               SUM(AgtFare),
               SUM(AgtSearch)
          FROM HitsAgent
         WHERE AgtPeriod = N'2010-10'
      GROUP BY agtperiod, agtpcc) AS x
GROUP BY x.period, x.pcc
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Adding the as T and T designation worked.  Thank you everyone for your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have access to create a
>   temporary table (company restricts
>   ability to create or modify tables) or
>   I would use that to solve this
>   problem.

Instead of a temporary table, try using a table variable:

```
declare @t table (id int primary key, col1 varchar(50))
insert @t (col1) values ('hello table variable')
select * from @t
```

A table variable can do most of the things a temporary table can.

Like Martin's (now deleted) answer suggests, consider giving the subquery an alias, like:

```
select  ... list of columns ...
from    (
        ... subquery ...
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        col1
```

And in your subquery, the `having` should probably be a `where`:

```
...
FROM        HitsAaa
WHERE       (AAAPeriod = N'2010-10') 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your first line to

```
Select T.Period, T.PCC, SUM(T.BasicHits), SUM(T.FareHits), SUM(T.SearchHits)
```

and the last line to

```
) T GROUP BY T.Period, T.PCC
```

You need to define a table alias (in this case T) for inner tables

Also, you need to `GROUP BY` the inner queries

Comment: +1: Table aliases don't have to be used, but SQL Server does require they be defined for derived tables/inline views.

Answer (score -1):

select  R."Artigo", R."Dscription" as "Descricao",
R."Codigo", R."Cliente",
R."ItmsGrpCod", Sum(R."Qtd/Kg") as "Qtd/Kg", Sum(R."Valor") as "Valor",
Sum(R."Valor")/Sum(R."Qtd/Kg") as "PMVL"
from (
select  T1."ItemCode" as "Artigo", T1."Dscription",
T0."CardCode" as "Codigo", T0."CardName" as "Cliente",
T3."ItmsGrpCod", Sum(T1."Quantity")*-1 as "Qtd/Kg",
Sum(T1."LineTotal")*-1 as "Valor",
( Sum(T1."LineTotal") / Sum(T1."Quantity") ) as "PMVL"
from
ORIN T0  INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
RIGHT JOIN OITM T3 ON  T1."ItemCode" = T3."ItemCode"
LEFT JOIN IBT1 T2 ON T0."DocEntry" = T2."BaseEntry" AND T1."ItemCode"=T2."ItemCode" and T2."BaseLinNum"=T1."LineNum"
where T0."DocDate"  >= ('2021-03-19') and T0."DocDate" <= ('2021-03-19')
and T3."ItmsGrpCod" like '___'
and T0.CANCELED = 'N'
group by T1."ItemCode", T1."Dscription", T0."CardCode", T0."CardName", T3."ItmsGrpCod"
union
-- facturas

select  T1."ItemCode" as "Artigo", T1."Dscription",
T0."CardCode" as "Codigo", T0."CardName" as "Cliente",
T3."ItmsGrpCod", Sum(T1."Quantity") as "Qtd/Kg",  Sum(T1."LineTotal") as "Valor", ( Sum(T1."LineTotal") / Sum(T1."Quantity") ) as "PMVL"
from
OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
-- LEFT JOIN OITM T3 ON  T1."ItemCode" = T3."CardCode"
left JOIN OITM T3 ON  T1."ItemCode" = T3."ItemCode"
-- INNER JOIN OITM T3 ON  T3."ItemCode" = T3."CardCode"
LEFT JOIN IBT1 T2 ON T0."DocEntry" = T2."BaseEntry" AND T1."ItemCode"=T2."ItemCode" and T2."BaseLinNum"=t1."LineNum"

```
    where T0."DocDate"  >= ('2021-03-19') and T0."DocDate" <= ('2021-03-19') 
    and T3."ItmsGrpCod" like '___' 
    group by T1."ItemCode", T1."Dscription", T0."CardCode", T0."CardName",T3."ItmsGrpCod"
    ) as R
    group by R."Artigo", R."Dscription", R."Codigo", R."Cliente",R."ItmsGrpCod"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.