# MySQL Multiple Joins to a Calendar Table For Payments Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an order table that looks like the below

```
order_id  pre_pay_time    pre_pay_amount    pre_pay_type    final_payment_time    final_payment_amount    final_payment_type   
==============================================================================================================================
1           1234123413           10           1               1234123913               25                    2     
2           1234123414           25           1               0                        100                   0       
3           1234123417           75           2               1234125416               155                   1        
4           0                     0           0               1234126418               60                    2
```

Here the customer can either make a pre payment on the order and then pay the remainder at the end, or they can just pay the full amount at the end.

The pre_pay_time and final_payment_time columns are UNIX timestamps.

What I'm trying to do is produce an output table that has the sum amounts for each calendar day. To do this I am joining with a calendar table.

Currently I am able to successfully output the data only for the sum of the final payment, as well as sums for cash and card payment (based on final_payment_type column) for each day of the month.

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, IFNULL( SUM( orders.final_payment_amount ) , 0 ) AS total_sales,
IFNULL(sum(if(final_payment_type=1,orders.final_payment_amount,0)),0)AS total_cash,
IFNULL(sum(if(final_payment_type=2,orders.final_payment_amount,0)),0)AS total_card,
count(orders.id) AS order_counter
FROM orders
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( cast(orders.final_payment_time as signed) ) ) = calendar.datefield ) 
WHERE calendar.datefield >= '2016-4-1' AND calendar.datefield <= '2016-4-31'
GROUP BY DATE
```

What I'm hoping to do is expand the query so that I also get sum values for each day for the pre_pay_amount based on the pre_pay_time. This will allow me to calculate total revenue for the day as a combination of final_payment_amount and pre_pay_amount.

Since the pre payment may be made on a different day to the final payment I believe that I will have to do another JOIN to the same calendar table using the pre_pay_time column.

Is this possible to do with one query?

Comment: is the date field a DATE without the timestamp on the calendar table?

Comment: yes, calendar.datefield is YYYY-MM-DD. That's why I'm having to convert the unixtimestamps to DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this....You alias your pre and final payment queries and then join them by datefield.

```
 SELECT *
  FROM (  SELECT calendar.datefield AS FinalDate,
                 IFNULL (SUM (orders.final_payment_amount), 0)
                    AS total_final_sales,
                 IFNULL (
                    SUM (
                       if (final_payment_type = 1,
                           orders.final_payment_amount,
                           0)),
                    0)
                    AS total_final_cash,
                 IFNULL (
                    SUM (
                       if (final_payment_type = 2,
                           orders.final_payment_amount,
                           0)),
                    0)
                    AS total_final_card,
                 COUNT (orders.id) AS order_final_counter
            FROM orders
                 RIGHT JOIN calendar
                    ON (DATE (
                           FROM_UNIXTIME (
                              CAST(orders.final_payment_time AS signed))) =
                           calendar.datefield)
           WHERE     calendar.datefield >= '2016-4-1'
                 AND calendar.datefield <= '2016-4-31'
        GROUP BY FinalDate) finalPay,
       (  SELECT calendar.datefield AS PreDate,
                 IFNULL (SUM (orders.pre_payment_amount), 0) AS total_pre_sales,
                 IFNULL (
                    SUM (
                       if (pre_payment_type = 1, orders.pre_payment_amount, 0)),
                    0)
                    AS total_pre_cash,
                 IFNULL (
                    SUM (
                       if (pre_payment_type = 2, orders.pre_payment_amount, 0)),
                    0)
                    AS total_pre_card,
                 COUNT (orders.id) AS order_pre_counter
            FROM orders
                 RIGHT JOIN calendar
                    ON (DATE (
                           FROM_UNIXTIME (
                              CAST(orders.pre_payment_time AS signed))) =
                           calendar.datefield)
           WHERE     calendar.datefield >= '2016-4-1'
                 AND calendar.datefield <= '2016-4-31'
        GROUP BY PreDate) prePay
 WHERE prePay.PreDate = finalPay.FinalDate
```

Comment: This looks like a neat solution, I'm going to go and test and see how expensive it is. Will report back.

Comment: This worked really well. Thank you so much. There was some small tidying up that was needed... You cannot have a space after declaring CAST as this throws an error, and the GROUP BY needed to be FinalDate and PreDate rather than DATE. I've submitted edits for this.

Answer (score 0):

For readability ( your mileage on what constitutes readability may vary! ) I often handle stuff like this with a temp table.

That is, I'd write the query to calculate the pre_pay_amount sum and insert that into a temp table, along with the date. Then join that temp table to this query on date.

I find using a temp table often saves fiddling around with the group clause to get the sum to work properly.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I am looking into temporary tables. What would the date join look like in the query after I've created the temp table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a UNION. The second query will be similar to the one you have for final payments and use the pre_payment columns. Then connect them with a UNION and SUM with a HAVING clause. Here's a good example of how to do that: [Sum a union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613728/sum-a-union-query)